# Angular JS get selected item value li html

Tags: angularjs

I have angular list and want to get selected value of it but its only working on click event

```
<div ng-hide="hideCustomerDropdown" id="customer-dropdown" class="slidedown-menu">
<div class="slidedown-header">
</div>
<div class="slidedown-body">
<ul class="customer-list list-unstyled">
<li ng-repeat="customers in customerArray" >
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></span>{{ customers.customer_name }} ({{ customers.customer_mobile || customers.customer_email }})       
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$("#customer-name").on("click", function() {
            $scope.showCustomerList(true);       
        });

  $scope.showCustomerList = function (isClick) {
            $http({
                url: API_URL ,
                method: "GET",
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: "json"
            }).
            then(function(response) {
                $scope.hideCustomerDropdown = false;
                $scope.customerArray = [];
                window.angular.forEach(response.data, function(customerItem, key) {
                    if (customerItem) {
                        $scope.customerArray.push(customerItem);
                    }
                });
    
            }, function(response) {
                window.toastr.error(response.data.errorMsg, "Warning!");
            });
        };
```

Comment: what do you mean by this : `to get selected value of id. its only workin g on click event` ? can you explain

Comment: How do you select item? On click save selected item in some variable or set some property on item.

Comment: @BillP see edit

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand your question but try to re-render your template by adding

`$scope.$apply();`

at the end of your `then` function.